# possible to detect webapp or mobile browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working with web application (iOS/Android)

Basically, My application looks like

- Basically it is just webpage
- Application wrapped it with WebView
- So technically, user can access the page with mobile browser(like Safari, Chrome, etc even PC Web browser) and Mobile Application

what I trying to do is detecting request from user is form Mobile Application or mobile browser.(with javascript)

Is it even possible?
If yes, recommend the method(I prefer native javascript since project is commercial)

Thanks.

P.S. I do not need device detect with `navigator.userAgent`, purpose of this job is detecting mobile browser or mobile app, not which device user uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom user agent string for your application webview so that you can distinguish a webview from js
For android you can use

```
myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(<your custom user agent string>);
```

It is better to append extra string to the actual useragent string

```
myWebView.getSettings.getSettings().setUserAgentString(myWebView.getSettings().getUserAgentString() + <your custom user agent string>);
```

You can check whether the user agent string contains the custom extra string from JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Jobin. However, I do not have any authority to access mobile code. Is there any way to achieve this with native javascript?(I can alter code browser side only)

Comment: There is no other way to distinguish which call is mobile app or mobile browser with native javascript. So I received extra parameter when the call is from mobile app. The problem solved, but I am not happy with that.(It feels some how does not natural)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize user agent like this:

```js
const withDetectDevice = (ua = window.navigator.userAgent, bp_mobile = 768) => {
  ua = ua.toLowerCase().trim()
  const isIOS = ua.includes('iphone') || ua.includes('ipod') || ua.includes('ipad')
  const isAndroid = ua.includes('android')

  const CHECKPOINT = {
    'isMobile': isAndroid || ua.includes('iphone'),
    'ios': isIOS,
    'andriod': isAndroid,
    'iphone': ua.includes('iphone'),
    'isChromeIos': ua.includes('crios'),
    'isFacebook': ua.includes('fbios') || ua.includes('fb_iab'),
    'isInstagram': ua.includes('instagram'),
    'isLine': ua.includes(' line/'), 
    'isSafari': /safari\/[0-9.]+$/.test(ua),
    'isChrome': ua.includes('chrome')
  }
  return CHECKPOINT;
}


// Usage
const  { isMobile, ios, isChrome, isInstagram } = withDetectDevice()

console.log( {isMobile}, {ios}, {isChrome}, {isInstagram} )
```